# The last version of Visual Studio (update2) TACO (release 9) failed to build at end on a big app (>700mb)

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, taco

I've updated my build tools, i'm now using :

- Visual Studio 2015 update 2
- Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova update 9

  TACO using Node 0.12.9 (autodownload on building, no control)
- Cordova CLI 6.1.1
- Building for iOS 9.3 with remotebuild.

This no longer works. Do you have an idea ?

See the VS build log (in french sorry) :

```
Fin de la génération 2701 (IDTâche:9)
------ Fin du téléchargement des fichiers de build de http://192.168.1.10:3000/cordova/build/2701/download vers D:\####\bld\iOS\Release (IDTâche:9)
------ Fin du téléchargement des sorties de génération vers D:\####\bld\iOS\Release (IDTâche:9)
------ Extraction des sorties de génération vers D:\####\bin\iOS\Release (IDTâche:9)
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FATAL ERROR: node::smalloc::Alloc(v8::Handle<v8::Object>, size_t, v8::ExternalArrayType) Out Of Memory
22:44:56.633     1>
MDAVSCLI : FATAL error : node::smalloc::Alloc(v8::Handle<v8::Object>, size_t, v8::ExternalArrayType) Out Of Memory
Exécution de la tâche "MdaVsCli" terminée -- ÉCHEC. (IDTâche:9)
```

Comment: Did it work before the updating? I mean, the same project and same target device, only the build tools changed?

Comment: yes, it work before with the same project, same device, only the build tools have changed.

Comment: Can you run this from the command line on Cordova, with verbose build ?

Comment: I have the same question as @axemclion. I work on the Visual Studio team and it would help us figure out how to troubleshoot this if we know that the build works fine using Cordova directly without remotebuild. Thanks for any updates!

Comment: With Cordova 6.2 (selected in config.xml), it's now ok.
Thanks!